# how to run GIT commands

Tags: android, eclipse, git, paho, android-open-accessory

I am new to Android Open Accessor `AOA`, and I wanted to download `paho` library designed for Android service.

I read this documentaion [here](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/), but it says in the section of `Building from source` that I have to apply this command

`git clone http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git`

I really do not know where to run this command? is it a `cmd` command or what? i really do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Linux(Considering Ubuntu Here) then you need to install git first

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

then in terminal you can use to clone the repo in local directory

```
git clone http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git
```

if you are on windows install git on windows follow instructions for git on their site: http://git-scm.com/downloads